# Вызов функции с помощью @

Tags: python, синтаксис

Подскажите что означает вызов функции с помощью символа @

```
@timeout
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656

Comment: Это декоратор. Это указании функции, что оборачивает другую функцию (под декоратором)

Answer (score 5):

Это синтаксис декоратора.

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator).

Пример:

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time


def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print('func:%r args:[%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec' %
            (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts))
        return result
    return wrap


@timing
def f(a):
    for _ in range(a):
        i = 0
    return -1


f(100000000)  # Вывод: func:'f' args:[(100000000,), {}] took: 1.9272 sec
```

Comment: Пример кода в ответе - для Python2 (актуальность Python2 сейчас довольно низкая). Я исправил его, чтобы работало под Python3. Зачем откатывать эту правку?

Comment: @insolor пример не мой, а из другого ответа. Я просто скопировал без изменений

Comment: @insolor сделал обратно, но без ссылки на другой ответ, чтобы не казалось, что там такой же.

Comment: Ссылку на ответ на en.so можно было и оставить, все-таки изменения чисто косметические.