# Как сделать замыкание в классе Pyton?

Tags: python, замыкания, декоратор

Как реализовать замыкания в классе, есть класс и есть 2 функции
само замыкание:

```
def _open(func):
    def actual(self):
        def wrapper():
            func()
        return wrapper
    return actual
```

и функция на которую я пытаюсь его применить:

```
@_open
def _create(self):
    # body
```

Класс

```
class MyClass:
    ...
    def _open(func):
        def actual(self):
            def wrapper():
                func()
            return wrapper
        return actual
    @_open
    def _create(self):
        # body
```

что я вызываю

```
my = MyClass(...)
my._create()
```

и хочу получить : вызов функции обернутый декоратором.

что я получаю : ничего, функция "вызвалась" но не вызвалась

Comment: Так что должен делать декоратор?

Comment: ну тут не суть что он должен делать, а суть в том, что функция теперь не юзается вообще

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1144256/394322

Comment: @вася, у меня вопрос не с этим, а с тем что у меня объявленны 2 функции в классе, одна декоратор и одна та на которую я юзаю декоратор, но когда я вызываю функцию ничег оне происходит

Comment: Как же не в этом, сравните как сделано у вас и как в примерах/документации.

Comment: @вася, в примере документации нет как оборачивать функции внутри класса, другими функциями этого класса

Comment: У вас в вопросе тоже класса нет. Приведите минимальный вопроизводимый пример с ожидаемым входом и выходом.

Comment: class myClass:
def _open(func):
    def actual(self):
        def wrapper():
            func()
        return wrapper
    return actual

@_open
def _create(self, cursor):
    # body

Comment: Все изменения и дополнения в сам вопрос с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1145193/edit)

Comment: @вася обнавлено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import wraps

class MyClass:
    def _open(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print('open')
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper

    @_open
    def _create(self):
        print('create')

my = MyClass()
my._create()
```

Comment: Ииии, оно так же не вызывает ничего)

Comment: В смысле не вызывает? Печатает и "open", и "create". Вы не сказали, что ещё надо вызвать.

Comment: *хочу получить : вызов функции обернутый декоратором* - это и происходит

Comment: да я уже допер, спасиб

Comment: кстати и без "@wraps(func)" работает

Comment: @lostlang https://stackoverflow.com/q/308999